# Need Regex format and help links

Tags: c#, regex

Am new to regex. Can anyone please tell me regex matches for the version number 10.0.10240.0? It will be helpful for me to proceed further.

Thanks

Comment: What are the valid ranges? Provide some examples of what should be matched and - often more importantly - what shouldn't.

Comment: [10.0.10240.0](http://refiddle.com/refiddles/56c30c5475622d3d79f71900)

Comment: use http://regexr.com/

Comment: @DavidHedlund, If the regex matches this type of version pattern(10.0.10240.0), i need to update the another version. i need the matching pattern for the same

Answer (score 1):

First of all you do not need Regex to parse versions, .Net has a builtin class for that called Version. ([ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version).)

You can use a tool for learning regex like Regulator.

Just to answer question here is my version of version regex

```
^(?<Major>\d+)\.(?<Minor>\d+)\.(?<Build>\d+)\.(?<Revision>\d+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex for your pattern

```
([0-9]{1,4}\.*)
```

and use global match .

For more, refer this [link](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: And did *you* refer to it? See [your `([0-9]{1,4}\.*)` regex in action](https://regex101.com/r/dT6bM0/1).

Comment: @Mhith: The input is a *single* version string. Why use *mutliple* matches? It is illogical - at least seems illogical to me.